# Hat dir der Film gefallen? oder Hat du der Film gefallen?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, personal-pronoun

> Hat dir der Film gefallen?

oder

> Hat du der Film gefallen?

I know first one is true but I do not understand why? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27627/lieben-vs-gefallen

Comment: The putative duplicate deals with a totally different topic, which is why I vote for reopening this question.

Comment: There are already several questions dealing with the question of which cases to use with 'gefallen" (or should I say: why gefallen has the same meaning as 'to like' in English but is used differently) so I'm voting for closing it again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The verb "gefallen" is used with dative. You can roughly think of it as "*to be pleasant to somebody*":

> Dieses Buch gefällt **mir** - this book is pleasant **to me**
>
> Der Schauspieler hat **ihr** gefallen - the actor was pleasant **to her**
>
> Hat **dir** der Film gefallen? - Was the film pleasant **to you**?