# Mir hat... warum Dativ?

Tags: dative

I have a sentence:

> Also ich war im Stadion und mir hat es gar nicht gefallen.

Why should I use Dativ (mir) in the case? Can someone give me a reference to the rule?

Comment: Have you seen the answer to: [Hat dir der Film gefallen? oder Hat du der Film gefallen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46563)

Comment: o, thanks! can you explain – what is the object in the and what is the subject in the case?

Comment: "Mir" is used as the object of the verb "gefallen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, ich war im Stadion, und mir hat es gar nicht gefallen.

These are two concatenated main clauses.

> Also, ich war im Stadion.

In this sentence, *ich* is the subject and *im Stadion* is an adverbial of location as a predicative.

> Mir hat es gar nicht gefallen.

In this sentence, *es* is the subject. One could assume *es* is the whole impression of being in the stadium, as told in the previous clause. Let's assume it was the game which did not meet your standards.

> Das Spiel gefällt nicht.

*The game does not please.*

While this sentence is valid, it's common to tell who has the bad impression.

> Das Spiel gefällt **mir** nicht.
>
> Das Spiel gefällt **ihm** nicht.

As this person is the **receiver** of the impression, it has to be a dative object.

Please note this is somewhat arbitrary. Some verbs require a receiver, other verbs treat their object as a mere target:

> Das Spiel trifft **meinen Geschmack** nicht.

Here, *meinen Geschmack* is an accusative object, because *treffen* requires a target, not a receiver.